# Is there a good/standard way to find the equivalent to this part but for a different connector?

Tags: usb, connector

I'm looking for a USB connector part. I've found [one part](https://www.digikey.ca/products/en?keywords=%20WM17115-ND) that has the right mount, but it has the wrong USB connector (in this case it is a mini USB).

Is there a good way for me to look for a part that has the same mounting but for micro-USB or for USB-C?  No idea how to do a search either at Digikey or at Molex to do this.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You won't find a footprint and pin compatible usb c connector. Micro b maybe. Check molex site for your part and they may have a micro listed on its page. If not check molex for through hole micro connectors. Very few available in THT.

Comment: Questions are required to stand alone without relying on links for key information.  *Describe* what you are looking for, don't just link to the similar thing.

Comment: The part you have is a through hole right angle USB receptacle. If you are looking for that is a USB-C it is available. If you want it to fit the exact same foot print as a mini USB that will not happen. If you explain a little bit more what you are looking for I would be happy to help try and find you a part.

Comment: On the topic of links, that one is also broken.

Answer (score 0):

You want to find a different part with the same footprint.

Unfortunately there's no standards body regulating USB connector  footprints, and all digikey offers is "mounting type" = "Through Hole, Right Angle"

Type C has more than 5 cable pins, so fitting type C there is not going to work, USB 2.1 Micro B OTOH does have 5 cable pins so you just need to find a connector with the right footprint.

searching on digikey finds no suitable usb micro connectors,  all the right-angle micro connectors seem to use surface mount terminations for the data pins. you'll have to pick one that fits the mounting holes used by the mini socket and extend those pins to reach the pads that the mini socket used.